# Migrating from MVC4 to MVC3 or changing Razor version V2 to V1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

I was developing an application in MVC4 and now I added new packages "mvcinstalled.mvc3" and "securityGuard". After Implementation I got an error below. I know both of these packages are compatible for razor version V1 not for V2. Could Anybody suggest any solution how to migrate from Razor V2 to V1 or migrating complete application to MVC3?

```
 [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to       
 [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from  
 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.
 0__31bf3856 
 ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 
 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 
 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0
 __31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web   
 request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where  
 it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException:   
 [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to  
 [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 
 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 
 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0
 __31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from  
 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location    
 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0
 __31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
```

Comment: Anybody have idea please?

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this problem, I started developing everything in MVC4 now rather than moving to mvc3.